# Five-page checkout equivalent of onepage success action?

Tags: checkout, event-observer, google-analytics

I have an observer programmed for the checkout_onepage_controller_success_action and need to know the corresponding event that I should use if the user has onepage checkout off and is using the default.

```
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <myextension>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>myextension/observer</class>
                    <method>handlePurchaseEvent</method>
                </myextension>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

This event doesn't fire on success of the normal 5-step checkout flow.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `checkout_submit_all_after`. This is dispatched in the following:

- `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api::createOrder()`
- `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create::createOrder()`
- `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Multishipping::createOrders()`
- `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder()`

If you're using a custom checkout extension, I'd assume that it would also dispatch this event.

It is dispatched after the quote has been converted into an order via `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitOrder`, payment charged etc, so if the event is dispatched you can rely on the checkout having been completed successfully.

Comment: So I should use `checkout_submit_all_after` instead of what I have then? Thanks!